# new wordpress website not sending mail on google cloud

Tags: wordpress, smtp, google-cloud-platform, office365

I am hosting my site on google cloud platform and the server is working fine (used the Bitnami deployment manager option).
I’m now trying to set up the WP-Mail-SMTP email plugin, however, Google blocks the outgoing ports for email and I can’t setup the connection. My email is being hosted on office 365 and all config options are correct but I don’t know how to setup the page to get around the blocked ports.
Thanks

Comment: `Google blocks the outgoing ports for email` what testing have you done to confirm this? Which ports are you interested in? Are there any firewall configuration options you have available in your control panel? I would expect wordpress to connect to the mail server via SMTP over ports 465 & 587.

Comment: This is stated in the google cloud documents [here](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/tutorials/sending-mail/). I also tested sending emails from using the wp-mail-smtp plugin test email option.

Answer (score 0):

Install smtp mail https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-mail-smtp/ and do the settings

It will resolved your issue if your firewall is not blocking the mails..

Comment: I am using that plugin but GCP blocks the email ports 25, 465 & 587. I'm using Office365 as my email provider so the test emails from wp-mail-smtp don't reach that port

Comment: try to do the setting like below link : https://support.office.com/en-gb/article/POP-and-IMAP-account-settings-cb41d2b8-98cb-4ab2-ad60-218349f37e2e?ui=en-US&rs=en-GB&ad=GB